# How to store and update deeply nested structures in ImmutableJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, redux, immutable.js

I am building little blog with react+redux and I cant figure out how should I go about replying to comments under blog post.
I am getting comments structure for one blog post which looks something like this.

```
"[
{"_id":"5676ed8b9104691f3b85b687",
"content":"Lorem",
"creator":"Admin",
"replies":[
  {
    "_id":"5676ede4b7a9044c3c1d9641",
    "content":"Ipsum",
    "creator":"Admin",
    "replies":[
      {
        "_id":"5676eec224ab8fe23c7ce4c6",
        "content":"Dolor",
        "creator":"Admin",
        "replies":[]
      },
      {
        "_id":"5676eeda1c0e3d093d1f90a0",
        "content":"Sit",
        "creator":"Admin",
        "replies":[]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id":"5676ee5b4b03bbac3c1f7544",
    "content":"Amet",
    "creator":"Admin",
    "replies":[]
  },
  {
    "_id":"5676ee91c43c05c63c319ace",
    "content":"Sup",
    "creator":"Admin",
    "replies":[]
  }
]},
{...}
]
```

How do I store it in ImmutableJS state so I can easily add replies to comments based on their `_id`? Also the comments have to be iterable because Im rendering them into comment tree afterwards but I dont think that should be a problem as long as ImmutableJS data structures are used. Basically I dont know how I should implement this function in my reducer.

```
[REPLY_COMMENT]: (state, { payload }) => {
  const { _id, comment } = payload
  let newState = ???
  return newState
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zedeqovuqa/edit?js,console) showing what I am trying to achieve. I just want to be able to reply to comments that's all

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, you can convert the above mutable `Array` with nested `Objects` using `Immutable.fromJS` method. Is that what you're asking? This will generate an `Immutable.List` with `Immutable.Map` as the data type of the comment items.

Comment: I added jsbin, please take a look. I know I can use `Immutable.fromJS` but how do I add data to specific comment replies then? Imagine you are building comments section under blog what approach and `ImmutableJS` data structure would you choose?

Answer (score 0):

You gotta break this down a bit.

So firstly let's add the comments to an `Immutable.Map`

```
state = state.update('coolPostId', post => Immutable.fromJS(comments));

const replyToPostComment = {
  _id: '1234',
  content: 'Hello',
  creator: 'RandomUser',
  replies: []
};
```

You now have an `Immutable.List` under `coolPostId`, so you then want to `update` that list by `push`ing a new comment:

```
state = state.update('coolPostId', comment => comment.push(Immutable.fromJS(replyToPostComment)));
```

That'll pass your first test:

```
const expected = state.get('coolPostId').last();
expect(expected.toJS()).to.deep.equal(replyToPostComment);
```

The second part is just as easy but you need to map cover your comments and check if the `_id` matches your metadata.

Here's your setup:

```
const replyComment = {
  _id: '5678',
  content: 'Wellcome',
  creator: 'RandomUser2',
  replies: []
};

const reply = {
  postId: 'coolPostId',
  commentId: '1234',
  comment: replyComment
};
```

The next line depends on a function that will do the `_id` check,

```
state = state.get(reply.postId)
  .map(comment => addReply(comment)(reply));
```

And the final bit of the puzzle is the `addReply` predicate:

```
const addReply = c => cr => c.get('_id') === cr.commentId ? c
  .update('replies', replies => replies.push(Immutable.fromJS(cr.comment)) ) : c;
```

Here is a full [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/medigam/40/edit?js,console) for review

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure if that would work for deeply nested comment replies? Like if comment have reply and that reply have more replies and so on. The postId+commentId pair to what I want to reply can be deep inside the comment tree.

Comment: you can replace `addReply` with `comment.updateIn`, see the docs.

Comment: Can you edit your example with the `updateIn` please? I can't make it work and from your response it seems like easy fix. I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: Can you update the model in your jsbin to show what a reply of a reply of a reply... looks like because it's not entirely clear. The keys between the reply and the reply comment don't match and I'm unsure of what it looks like when that's a level down the tree? How would you know what the parent is in the scenario you've outlined above?

Comment: Comment can have another comments in its `replies` property. There is just one model. Reply is comment inside another comment `replies` property. Like tree structure where one node can have many children nodes and so on. And I think keys in my example make sense I added root comment with `_id: '1234'` and replied to it with `_id: '5678'`

Comment: So how do you reply to a reply of a reply? What would that look like with the root comment? That's not clear to me.

Comment: Your `reply` only has properties that are three levels deep: `postId` -> `commentId` -> `reply`

Comment: I dont see how that changes anything. You can have any dept you like with structure I provided. Edit: Now I see what is not clear, I forgot to add `properties` to my reply. Sorry, every comment have `replies` property

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly is preventing structure I provided to became tree of any depth please? So maybe I can edit my question to be more clear.